# multiple SpaCy doc objects and want to combine them into one object

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, doc

I am trying to tokenize a text file of the King James bible but when I attempt it I get a memory error.  So I have divided the text up into multiple objects.  Now I want to use spaCy to tokenize the objects and then recombine them into one doc object. I have seen others talking about similar issues and converting into arrays and then back to a doc after combining the arrays.  Will this work to fix my issue or create new issues later?

I tried running this but colab nor my computer do not have the RAM to support it.

```
nlp_spacy = spacy.load('en')
kjv_bible  = gutenberg.raw('bible-kjv.txt')

#pattern for bracketed text titles
bracks = "[\[].*?[\]]"

kjv_bible = re.sub(bracks, "", kjv_bible)

kjv_bible =  ' '.join(kjv_bible.split())

len(kjv_bible)

kjv_bible_doc = nlp_spacy(kjv_bible)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-19-385936fadd40> in <module>()
----> 1 kjv_bible_doc = nlp_spacy(kjv_bible)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/language.py in 
__call__(self, text, disable, component_cfg)
    378         if len(text) > self.max_length:
    379             raise ValueError(
--> 380                 Errors.E088.format(length=len(text), 
max_length=self.max_length)
    381             )
    382         doc = self.make_doc(text)

ValueError: [E088] Text of length 4305663 exceeds maximum of 1000000. 
The v2.x parser and NER models require roughly 1GB of temporary memory 
per 100,000 characters in the input. This means long texts may cause 
memory allocation errors. If you're not using the parser or NER, it's 
probably safe to increase the `nlp.max_length` limit. The limit is in 
number of characters, so you can check whether your inputs are too 
long by checking `len(text)`.



nlp.max_length = 4305663
kjv_bible_doc = nlp_spacy(kjv_bible)
```

results in crashing the notebook due to RAM memory

will this work

```
np_array = doc.to_array([LOWER, POS, ENT_TYPE, IS_ALPHA])
np_array.extend(np_array2)
doc2.from_array([LOWER, POS, ENT_TYPE, IS_ALPHA], np_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [Doc.from_docs](https://spacy.io/api/doc/#from_docs) to concatenate multiple Doc objects. Here is the example from the spaCy documentation:

```py
from spacy.tokens import Doc
texts = ["London is the capital of the United Kingdom.",
         "The River Thames flows through London.",
         "The famous Tower Bridge crosses the River Thames."]
docs = list(nlp.pipe(texts))
c_doc = Doc.from_docs(docs)
assert str(c_doc) == " ".join(texts)
assert len(list(c_doc.sents)) == len(docs)
assert [str(ent) for ent in c_doc.ents] == \
       [str(ent) for doc in docs for ent in doc.ents]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you increase the `max_length`, it will crash unless you explicitly disable the components that use a lot of memory (parser and NER). If you're only using the tokenizer, you can disable everything except the tokenizer when you load the model:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['tagger', 'parser', 'ner'])
```